# Execute a python script on button click

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I have an HTML page with one button, and I need to execute a python script when we click on the button and return to the same HTML page with the result.

So I need do some validation on return value and perform some action.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="home" onclick="validate()" value="checkvalue"></button>
```

**JS:**

```
function validate(){
    if (returnvalue=="test") alert(test)
    else alert ("unsuccessful")
}
```

What my python code is doing is some validation on the name entered in the text box and gives the return status.

But I need the result back on the same page, so I can do the form submission later with all the details. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Python runs at server side, so the closest you can get is to AJAX send the value to your server and return the validated result.

Comment: related: [How to connect Javascript to Python sharing data with JSON format in both ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747527/how-to-connect-javascript-to-python-sharing-data-with-json-format-in-both-ways)

Answer (score 15):

You can use Ajax, which is easier with [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```js
$.ajax({
   url: "/path/to/your/script",
   success: function(response) {
     // here you do whatever you want with the response variable
   }
});
```

and you should read [the jQuery.ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) since it has too many options.

Comment: In my case,  this code downloads python script file from file URL

Answer (score 12):

Make a page(or a service) in python, which can accept post or get request and process the info and return back a response. It is better if the response is in json format. Then you can use this code to make a call on the button click.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="home" onclick="validate()" value="checkvalue">
<script>
$('#id').click(function(){

 $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:<YOUR SERVERSIDE PAGE URL>,
      cache:false,
      data:<if any arguments>,
      async:asynchronous,
      dataType:json, //if you want json
      success: function(data) {
        <put your custom validation here using the response from data structure >
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        <put your custom code here to handle the call failure>
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @Hari May I ask what the $('#id') is doing? is the '#id' used here as a placeholder for us to replace with something like 'home' (in the case of OP's question)? If so, I'm still not sure what $ is doing

Comment: @hello_there_andy, the "id" is supposed to be replaced with the id of your html element. '#' denotes that it is an id jquery should be looking for. $ is the jquery object and it invokes the jquery library.