# Run python script and show result in django html page

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a python script named `t.py` inside this script code is:

```
a = 'Hello World'
```

Now I want to print this `'Hello World'` at the webpage if I click the button by using django framework.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a python script on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151133/execute-a-python-script-on-button-click)

Comment: I am guessing this can be done by editing views.py and url.py

Comment: sorry @Troyer that is different question, my question is only concerned about django.