# Send JSON data to the front end in Flask

Tags: python, json, web-applications, flask

Just wondering how can you send JSON data to the front end of a web app using Flask. Don't have that much experience with it, just looking for some ideas?

Comment: The same way you'd send JSON to any webapp — could you give more details here?

Comment: What's the general flow of sending JSON to a webapp? Do you have any good tutorials/links that explains it?

Comment: [How to connect Javascript to Python sharing data with JSON format in both ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11747527/4279) contains a hello-world example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dictionary Dict.

If Dict is your dictionary, you can just do

```
return flask.jsonify(**Dict)
```