# Launch python script from html button without return

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I try to launch python script form HTML button. My python script work on text files and reorganize them in folders, so it doesn't have return, it's only an action.

This is my python script

```
import os

# Compress tabfile

folder_edition  = 'D:\\folder_edition'
folder_destination = 'D:\\folder_destination'

for the_file in os.listdir(folder_edition):

    if the_file.endswith(".tab"):

        fichier_source = folder_edition + "\\" + the_file
        fichier_temporaire = folder_compress + "\\" + the_file + "_temp.tab"
        fichier_compress = folder_compress + "\\" + the_file.replace("edition_","cclo_")

        print fichier_source

        result = file(fichier_source,"r").read().replace("  ", " ").replace("     ", " ").replace("    ", " ").replace("   ", " ").replace("  ", " ").strip()
        file(folder_compress + "\\" + the_file + "_temporaire.tab","w").write(result)

        fichier_in = open(fichier_temporaire,"r")
        fichier_out = open(fichier_compress, "w")

        for ligne in fichier_in:
            if not (ligne.startswith("#") or ligne.startswith(" #") or ligne.startswith("  #") or ligne.startswith("   #") or ligne.startswith("    #") or ligne.startswith("     #")):
                fichier_out.write(ligne)

        fichier_in.close()
        fichier_out.close()

        f = file(fichier_compress,"r")
        chaine = f.read()
        f.close() 
        result=chaine.replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " ")
        f = file(fichier_compress,"w")
        f.write(result)
        f.close()

        os.remove(fichier_temporaire)
```

And I tried to call it with a button in HTML

```
<html>
<div id = "global">
    <button class="button_tab" onclick="admin_tab('compress')">Compress</button>
</div>
</html>
```

And my script where I call my script with Ajax and JQuery

```
function admin_tab(var_operation)
{
    if (var_operation = 'compress') {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: 'script\\python\\compress.py',
            timeout: 3000,
            async:true,
            success: function(response){
                alert('Yes !');
            },
            error: function() {
              alert('No !'); }
        });
    }
};
```

When I click on the button, HTML correctly read my Python script, but I've any action in folders ...

What can I do for have a similar action, like double click ?

Comment: It's not clear why you thought this would work. It can *access* the file, sure, but *execute* it?

Comment: So how can I execute this script ?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11747527/3001761

Comment: I don't understand the answers of the other post

Comment: You will need to be more specific than *"don't understand"*. Spend some time on research, then if you still are unclear [edit] this question to describe precisely what you still need to know. See [ask].

Comment: You need to run the script on the server, take a look at Flask. You can wrap the script with a route decorator

Comment: It's just not the same case, I don't need connection to database, I just want to wrtie and reorder folders

Comment: Thank you  Sinan Guclu, I tried to resolve my problem with Flask (I'm not a very good developper of python, it's for that what it's difficult for me to understand the answers of the other subject)

Comment: Do you know can I make an answer for this question ? I don't have button `Post your answer` and the answer of the other subject don't work for me...