# Connect Javascript with python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

I am currently working on a project which requires me to connect javascript with python.
the scenario is:
I have a simple form(name, email) using HTML and javascript and have to capture this in python. 
My analysis part is done in python.
I don't have much knowledge about javascript but I read online about Flask and was able to connect javascript using Flask.
How can I get the user input from javascript and transfer this into python?
Python can read JSON data but I don't have any idea as to how to capture the user data.

Comment: Get the form to POST the data to your Flask application and then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/how-to-get-data-received-in-flask-request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747527/how-to-connect-javascript-to-python-sharing-data-with-json-format-in-both-ways a previous post with the answer

Answer (score -2):

Jinja + Django are the go-to tools for using python as a backend language. Django is used for the back-end framework, whereas jinja is really useful for writing python code inside an HTML file. I have linked both below:

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

[Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that the OP asked.